# How to get the X value of a ticks from the x axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Hello I'm trying to understand [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL31s.png) and [this other example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL31s.png) to add grid lines to a stacked area.

```
tiksArray = [1900, 1950, 2000, 2010];
keys = ["Amanda", "Ashley", "Betty", "Deborah"];

// Add X axis
const dX = d3.extent(nbrOfBabies, d => d.year);
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(dX)
  .range([0, this.width]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${this.height})`)
  .call(this.make_x_gridlines(x)
    .tickSize(-this.height)
    .tickFormat(null)
  );

// gridlines in x axis function
make_x_gridlines(x) {
 const bttm = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickValues(this.tiksArray);
 return bttm;
}
```

I'm getting this graph. I'd like to know the X value of those ticks, i.e. **1900**, **1950**, 2000. I'd like to know where each line start so I can add a legend for each column.

[image]

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3, the axis generator uses the passed **scale** for positioning the ticks. Therefore, all you need to do is passing those values in your `tiksArray` to the same scale (in your case, `x`).

Here is a very basic demo:

```js
const ticksArray = [1900, 1950, 2000, 2010];
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1880, 2020])
  .range([50, 450]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${100})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickValues(ticksArray)
    .tickSizeInner(-100)
  );

ticksArray.forEach(d => {
  console.log("The SVG position of the tick " + d + " is: " + x(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.